# Проверка возраста “от и до” в выпадающем списке

Tags: javascript, jquery

При первом запуске возможен баг что первое число "От" больше второго "До"
Как избавиться от этого? И есть возможность не выключать другие числа а удалять их из этого списка?

http://jsfiddle.net/mmL5m2me/

```
for(i=18;i<=90;i++){
var option = "<option />";
option = jQuery(option);
option.attr('value',i);
option.html(i);
var copy = option.clone();
jQuery('#select-to').append(option);
jQuery('#select-from').append(copy);


jQuery(document).on('change','#select-to,#select-from',function(e){
    var el =jQuery(this).attr('id');
    window.val = jQuery(this).val();
    if(el=='select-from'){
        jQuery('#select-to').find('option').each( function(i,j){
            console.log(window.val);
                  if(jQuery(j).attr('value')<window.val) jQuery(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
               else jQuery(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    }
    if(el=='select-to'){
        jQuery('#select-from').find('option').each( function(){
                  if(jQuery(this).attr('value')>window.val) jQuery(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
               else jQuery(this).removeAttr('disabled','');
        });
    }
```

Comment: jQuery(this).css('display','none'); будет работать

Comment: Можно поподробнее куда это добавить?

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 1):

```js
// заполню селекты
for(i=18;i<=90;i++){
    var option = "<option />";
    option = jQuery(option);
    option.attr('value',i);
    option.html(i);
    var copy = option.clone();
    jQuery('#select-to').append(option);
    jQuery('#select-from').append(copy);
}                 
// Задам условия

jQuery(document).on('change','#select-to,#select-from',function(e){
        var el =jQuery(this).attr('id');
        window.val = jQuery(this).val();
        if(el=='select-from'){
            jQuery('#select-to').find('option').each( function(i,j){
                console.log(window.val);
                      if(jQuery(j).attr('value')<window.val)
                      {
                       jQuery(this).css('display','none')
                      }
                   else{
                     jQuery(this).css('display','block')
                   } 
            }); 
            jQuery('#select-to').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        if(el=='select-to'){
            jQuery('#select-from').find('option').each( function(){
                      if(jQuery(this).attr('value')>window.val) jQuery(this).css('display','none')
                   else jQuery(this).css('display','block');
            });
        }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="from" id="select-from">
</select>
<select name="to" id="select-to" disabled>
<option value="---">---</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! А что делать с багом в самом начале когда только открывается есть возможность выбрать первое значение больше второго что недопустимо по логике (от 34 до 18)

Comment: проверьте ответ, думаю так работает, нет бага

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: пожалуйста:) только отметьте ответ как правильный, спасибо